# call a javascript function inside tag library jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

How to call a javascript function in jsp within tab library. I have tried something like, below is my code.

JavaScript function:

```
    function myconfirmBox(msg){ alert(msg);}
```

JSP code:

```
<s:if test="Messages()">
            myconfirmBox("hello");
        </s:if>
```

What am i actually doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSP stuff runs **on the server**, your JavaScript code will run **on the client** (unless you're trying to integrate with Rhino, which I suspect is not the case). So what you've done there is actually output `myconfirmbox("hello");` as text on the page.

If you want it to be run as inline script, add `<script>` tags around it. But more likely you need to step back and take a look at the wider context, you probably want to wait for some kind of event to occur (even if it's just that the page is completely loaded) before showing a confirm box.

When writing dynamic server-side code, you always have to think about what will actually get sent to the browser to be interpreted. You can use tools like the Network tab in Chrome's Developer Tools to see what you're actually sending, so you can see what the browser is working with.